# Can't ping anything on local network - general failure

Tags: networking, ping, localhost, ipv4, icmp

When trying to ping another device within the local network (in same domain) it gives: `General Failure. Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)`. Huawei Matebook X Pro with latest version of Windows 10.

I tried the following without success:

- Different networks
- Disabled IPv6
- Disable all IPv4 or IPv6 transition technologies
- SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support (Enabled)
- Allow incoming echo request ICMP settings
- Disabled firewall and Antivirus
- resetting the TCP/IP and Winsock catalog
- Also with a external Wifi usb adapter

Any suggestions? Because it is annoying when trying to access a router / IP-Cam within the network.

Comment: have a look here. https://serverfault.com/questions/18506/what-to-check-if-pinging-doesnt-work

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve the problem.